# How do you get javascript/jquery to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I've gotten it squared away thanks to your help!

I am doing javascript/jquery tutorials on codeschool/codeacademy and everything seems to go fine there. But when I try to do something myself, I cannot get the javascript to actually trigger. I tried chrome and firefox. I disabled all plugin extentions. Must be a simple problem, please help!

The following code I cut and pasted from jquery (http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Here is a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/interestinall/n5mqryrj/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
            alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It does not work for me. Can someone explain why and tell me how to get it working? Thanks so much!

Comment: Consider to open your console when trying to debug a website... I'd look at the network tab

Comment: All is working well just wronly added url check http://jsfiddle.net/n5mqryrj/7/

Comment: Check the Path to "jquery.js"
The code seems to be correct.

Comment: The unique problem I can see is your include "jquery.js" in a wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres nothing wrong with your code. We were all started somewhere and some of these suggestions are misleading

If you're not already aware, jQuery is a comprehensive library which makes complex javascript development simpler. Its important to note that everything you do with jQuery can be achieved using  native javascript its just a little tricker and jquery handles all the complexities to work across a wide range of browsers. That is to say some things work in some browsers, where as others do things in a different way (notably IE).

To use jQuery on your website, you need to include it on your page. Its self executing and one way you can tell if its worked is running something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        console.log($)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you open the console in chrome (hit f12) you should see:

```
function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}
```

Note that I'm using `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"` for the source of the script. You can use `src="jquery.js"` as per your script, but it means you need to save the contents of https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js to a file called jquery.js at the same level as your index.html (or the wherever-you-saved-your-code.html)

Ive noted some suggestions say you should include jQuery in the  tag and, though this would work, its considered best practice to keep scripts at the bottom of the page for reasons I wont go into here.

As such, this should work for you (irregardless of browser extensions):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
            alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. This was indepth and exactly what I needed. I'd upvote it if it could.

Comment: Not to worry. Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You did not include jquery in your project.
change this line

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

to this line

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
```

or any other version in

https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

You've used the wrong URL to jquery. `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/jquery.js` gives a 404 error.

Try using an absolute URI or picking the library from the Frameworks & Extensions menu.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your jQuery properly. Try this instead:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>    
    <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
                alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
```

with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or download the jQuery-Scriptfile from jQuery.com, store it locally and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example
http://jsbin.com/pajecubute/1/edit

```
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
        alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle. You need not include JQuery separately in your HTML. It is already present for your selection on the left hand side. Your code works now.

http://jsfiddle.net/n5mqryrj/8/

Added `ready` function in the `script` section:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
        alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```